# Writing an if statement using jQuery's attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner with jQuery so is this code right? Also how can I call it when page loads?

I need to say if the skin is `"white"` change the website logo to the black logo.

```js
if ($("#themestyle").attr('href', "/web/assets/css/skins/white.css")) {
  $("#logo").attr('src', "/web/assets/images/LogoBlack.png");
} else {
  $("#logo").attr('src', "/web/assets/images/Logowhite.png");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="icon" href="/web/assets/images/favicon.ico">
  <title>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Test Website" />
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/assets/css/skins/blue.css" id="themestyle" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="/web/assets/images/Logowhite.png" id="logo" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: First you should import jQuery. Here there is no jQuery, that's why you get: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: should be `if ($("#themestyle").attr('href') === "/web/assets/css/skins/white.css")`

Comment: Why not using css `background-image` in your CSS file if the logo is part of your style?

Comment: To run jQuery logic when the page loads, place it in a document.ready event handler: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is because you're using the *setter* of `attr()` in the `if()`. This sets the `href` attribute then returns a jQuery object containing the `link` element. When coerced to a boolean this will always return `true`.

To fix this use the *getter* of `attr()` and use `==` to compare it to the known `href`, like this:

```
var filename = 'LogoBlack.png';
if ($("#themestyle").attr('href') == "/web/assets/css/skins/white.css") {
  filename = 'Logowhite.png';
}
$("#logo").attr('src', '/web/assets/images/' + filename);
```

Alternatively you can use a ternary expression. They're more succinct but, arguably, harder to read:

```
var filename = $("#themestyle").attr('href') == "/web/assets/css/skins/white.css" ? 'LogoBlack.png' : 'Logowhite.png';
$("#logo").attr('src', '/web/assets/images/' + filename);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and help it's working.

Comment: No problem, glad to help